# IE Protected Mode Problem?

Tags: internet-explorer, add-in

We've developed an ie-add (with add-in express) in which saves some information on locally. (to the application path) But without "run as administrator" or "disabling protected mode" it's not allowed.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Any way to load add-in with administrator privilige? (manifest files does not work for dll's) or any way to disable protected mode with user approval?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need to write there ? Some directories like the local user application data folder are accessible in protected modes and should be used for application settings according to microsoft.

Comment: unfortunately yes... there is an embedded db copied to application local and etc. is there any way to disable protected mode programmatically after user approval?

Comment: @EkinOzcicekciler Don't listen to people who keep saying things are impossible, these people don't understand that everything is possible. Check out my answer, it should answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to disable Protected Mode programmatically. I assume we have to live with it. Find some pointers of how to do this in: [HowTo: Deal with Protected Mode API in Internet Explorer 7 and IE8](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/06/12/internet-explorer-protected-mode-api/).

Answer (score 3):

[Understanding and Working in Protected Mode IE: Finding Low Integrity Write Locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28VS.85%29.aspx#wpm_fliwl).

Long and short of it: call [IEGetWriteableFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537314%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: so you mean it's impossible for us to save different location with protected mode enabled.

Comment: What I mean is that a Low Integrity process can only write to Low Integrity write locations.  That's the security model.  You have to work within it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

Fire up RegEdit and go to this key:

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones
```

On my machine (Windows 7) the Local System account is S-1-5-18. This might be the same for all versions of Windows, but I don't know about that.

In that registry key, there are five more keys 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 - each representing a Zone.

For every zone, if there is a `DWORD` value with the name `"2500"`, set its value to `0` to turn protected mode off. Note that you don't have to add it if it isn't there.

The value `"2500"` is supposed to control the tick box "Enable protected mode".

Or, if you want to just alter Protected Mode settings for Current User then go to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER version of the above registry key, and I think there may also be one for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (feel free to check) and use whichever one you prefer.

Comment: I am using a similar solution to what Erx_VB.NExT.Coder stated in his answer. The only exception is that for me the value 0 checks the box and the value 3 unchecks the box. Code is AutoIT ; Turns protected mode on for current user in Local Intranet Zone (3 turns it off) RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1", "2500", "REG_DWORD", 0)

Comment: Only worked when I changed the HKEY_CURRENT_USER version (omit the S-1-5-18). On Server 2003