# ActiveX .exe File Download

Tags: php, html, activex, download

I am working on a Web Installer for one of my projects and need to be able to download the .exe files using ActiveX. I do not want any dialogs prompting the user to do something with the download. After the user approves the ActiveX, I want the files to be downloaded to the proper place, say C:\TEST.

Any ideas?

**This is what I have so far:**

```
<?php

$filename = "WebLock.exe";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>

<html>
<head>

<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><b>Downloading Required Files...</b></center>
<script>
function IEsave(filename, sData) {
    var fso, a;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    file = fso.CreateTextFile(filename, 2, false);
    file.write(<?php echo $contents ?>);
    file.Close();
    return file;
}

alert(IEsave("C:\\WebLock.exe", ""));

</script>
Complete!
</body>
</html>
```

The only problem is, it doesn't write the file.

---

**Here is the actual page:**

[**Here is the published page!**](http://weblock.zbrowntechnology.info/Inst/webinst.php)

Comment: Is the site you are doing this from a trusted site in the user's IE?

Comment: You are writing an exe's file contents into the HTML? o.O

Comment: @Pekka, in most cases.. yes. But it will prompt the user to either allow or disallow the ActiveX. @Time Machine,  I thought I was writing the contents of the .exe into the file... am I not?

Comment: What @Time Machine says - probably better to fetch the data using Ajax. Plus, you are missing quotes around the contents I think

Comment: You write it into the HTML using the PHP inside the script. PHP is executed before the browser gets the HTML, you know.

Comment: Ok, so how do I get the contents of the .exe to the .exe on the HDD? I can't even seem to get it to write a simple text file.

Comment: @TimeMachine that's why he's using the FileSystemObject to write it. @Zachary sorry, I don't have experience with FSO so I don't know what needs troubleshooting. Is what you are using an up to date example from MSDN?

Comment: @Pekka, I can't seem to find anything about this on MSDN.

Comment: @Zachary you should get an error if it's not working. No errors?

Comment: None displayed on the page and none in the Server logs.

Comment: @Pekka, I've added the link to the actual page in my original post. It is supposed to write a file (C:/Test1.txt (.txt for testing purposes)) with 'Hello" as the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write a file to any location due to IE’s Protected Mode feature, even if you write your own plug-in.

I had the same problem and my solution was writing files to low integrity location and calling shell’s SHFileOperation for making copy with UAC dialog.

But If possible, you can try to add your site to trusted list for all of your users.

Here is related question: [IE Protected Mode Problem?!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966950/ie-protected-mode-problem)

Comment: I had this workign, then it just stopped. I've tried everything I can think of. I've tested it in IE8, IE9 and Opera.

Comment: What do you mean? Did you write your own ActiveX or you have added site to the trusted list?